# How to make a complex robot model in webots?

Tags: 3d-modelling, 3d-model, webots

I make my robot using cyberbotics webots. I can’t figure out how to make a beautiful 3D model. At least at the mantis hexapod level.
I understand that you can import ready-made fraud only in vrml97 format, but it is not supported by fusion 360 and other programs.
But in webots itself, I did not find a way to build a model more complicated than using cubes, pyramids, and other simple objects.
There was also an idea to assemble a model from a large number of rectangles using grouping, but it seems to me that such a model will greatly slow down.
Is it possible to see how the finished robots are made, and make changes to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node you are looking for is the IndexedFaceSet https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/indexedfaceset, it allows you to efficiently model a shape using a set of triangle faces, you will find an example of this in this simulation world: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/samples-geometries#high_resolution_indexedfaceset-wbt

One possible workflow to do this is to use Blender to create your mesh and then use the Webots exporter to export it to Webots: https://github.com/cyberbotics/blender-webots-exporter

Comment: Thank you, while I was waiting for an answer, I already found it myself.
The only question remains is whether it is possible to use not a blender, but for example the Fusion 360, since I often use it and it is more convenient for me. I’ll try to make a model in it, and through a blender already convert it to a webots.

Comment: Unfortunately, Fusion 360 does not provide VRML exportation. But as a workaround, you can do your design in Fusion 360 and then export in a standard format (such as STL or OBJ) and use a software (such as Blender) just for conversion, or even use a free online conversion service, such as: https://cloud.cadexchanger.com/

Comment: I have already done so. And there is an interesting subtlety: I tried both stl and obj. And in the end, obj turned out to be much more convenient, because in it separate parts of the model are stored separately, and also groups and names of groups and objects are stored in it, which in the end helped me a lot at the stage of assembling the robot in Webots. Robot completed: https://www.instagram.com/p/B89TGkxKiUP/